# How can I print this data on two pages?

Tags: c#

Code:

```
            void printDocument_PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e)
        {
            int left = 75;


            Graphics graphic = e.Graphics;
            Font font = new Font("tahoma", 10);
            Pen p = new Pen(Brushes.Black, 1.5f);

            Bitmap logo = new Bitmap(SpectraPetrochemicals.Properties.Resources.SpectraLogoForPrint);


            float logoX = (e.PageSettings.PaperSize.Width / 2) - (logo.HorizontalResolution);
            float logoY = 30;

            graphic.DrawImage(logo, logoX, logoY);


Suppose from this point on I want to print it on the next page.

     graphic.DrawString("Time: " + txtCredtSaleTime.Text, font, Brushes.Black, 400, 175);
            graphic.DrawString("Sale No: " + txtCreditSaleNo.Text, font, Brushes.Black, left, 200);
            graphic.DrawString("Customer Name: " + cmbCreditCustomers.Text, font, Brushes.Black, 400, 200);

        }
```

How can I print this on two pages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to use the PrintPageEventArgs property; HasMorePages

> Gets or sets a value indicating whether an additional page should be printed.
>
> https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.printing.printpageeventargs.hasmorepages(v=vs.110).aspx

Then something along these lines;

```
private static void Print()
{
    bool firstPage = true;
    printDocument.PrintPage += (sender, args) =>
    {
        if (firstPage)
        {
            int left = 75;

            Graphics graphic = e.Graphics;
            Font font = new Font("tahoma", 10);
            Pen p = new Pen(Brushes.Black, 1.5f);

            Bitmap logo = new Bitmap(SpectraPetrochemicals.Properties.Resources.SpectraLogoForPrint);


            float logoX = (e.PageSettings.PaperSize.Width / 2) - (logo.HorizontalResolution);
            float logoY = 30;

            graphic.DrawImage(logo, logoX, logoY);

            firstPage = false;
            args.HasMorePages = true;

            return;
        }
        else
        {
            graphic.DrawString("Time: " + txtCredtSaleTime.Text, font, Brushes.Black, 400, 175);
            graphic.DrawString("Sale No: " + txtCreditSaleNo.Text, font, Brushes.Black, left, 200);
            graphic.DrawString("Customer Name: " + cmbCreditCustomers.Text, font, Brushes.Black, 400, 200);

            args.HasMorePages = false;
        }
    }
}
```